# Hyperthreading: There are not enough slots available

Tags: mpi, openmpi, hyperthreading

I tried to assign 4 tasks to 4 processors. Output of `hwloc-ls --of console` is:

```
L2 L#0 (256KB) + L1d L#0 (32KB) + L1i L#0 (32KB) + Core L#0
      PU L#0 (P#0)
      PU L#1 (P#2)
L2 L#1 (256KB) + L1d L#1 (32KB) + L1i L#1 (32KB) + Core L#1
      PU L#2 (P#1)
      PU L#3 (P#3)
```

from which I deduce that there are 2 cores and totally 4 processors. Graphically,

[image]

I made a rankfile according to [Hristo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11761943/1128551):

**Rankfile:**

```
rank 0=localhost slot=p0
rank 1=localhost slot=p2
rank 2=localhost slot=p1
rank 3=localhost slot=p3
```

and also added `-use-hwthread-cpus` option according to [Gilles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48836143/1128551) resulting in the following command:

```
mpirun -use-hwthread-cpus -n 4 -H localhost -rf rankfile ./a.out
```

However, I got error message:

> There are not enough slots available in the system to satisfy the 2
>   slots that were requested by the application.

I kept trying different rankfiles as [Hamy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15078793/1128551) hoping that the problem is related to way of referencing processors but still I got the error message for each combination. My OpenMPI version is 3.0.1.

Comment: What if you simply `mpirun --use-hwthreads-cpu -n 4 ./a.out` ?

Comment: It worked. But why it doesn't work when a rankfile is provided?

Comment: that looks like a bug you can report to the Open MPI users mailing list or https://github.com/open-mpi/ompi

Comment: as a workaround, you can use your real host name instead of `localhost` and do not use the `-H` option