# Ubuntu Fortran CoArray: f951: Warning: Nonexistent include directory ‘/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/../../fortran/gfortran-mod-15/openmpi’

Tags: fortran, mpi, gfortran, openmpi, fortran-coarrays

System:

```
Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish) 64-bit
Kernel Linux 5.15.0-46-generic x86_64
MATE 1.26.0
```

Installed packages:

```
gfortran --> gfortran-11
libgfortran-11-dev
libcaf-mpich-3
libcaf-openmpi-3
libcoarrays-dev
libcoarrays-mpich-dev
libcoarrays-openmpi-dev
```

Trying to compile a CoArrayFortran program via `caf caf01.f90` results in the error

```
f951: Warning: Nonexistent include directory ‘/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/../../fortran/gfortran-mod-15/openmpi’ [-Wmissing-include-dirs]
/usr/bin/ld: -lmpi_usempif08 kann nicht gefunden werden: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
/usr/bin/ld: -lmpi_usempi_ignore_tkr kann nicht gefunden werden: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
/usr/bin/ld: -lmpi_mpifh kann nicht gefunden werden: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
/usr/bin/ld: -lopen-rte kann nicht gefunden werden: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
/usr/bin/ld: -lopen-pal kann nicht gefunden werden: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
/usr/bin/ld: -lhwloc kann nicht gefunden werden: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
/usr/bin/ld: -levent_core kann nicht gefunden werden: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
/usr/bin/ld: -levent_pthreads kann nicht gefunden werden: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Error: comand:
   `/usr/bin/mpif90.openmpi -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/fortran/ -fcoarray=lib caf01.f90 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/open-coarrays/openmpi/lib/libcaf_openmpi.a`
failed to compile.
```

There is a directory `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/../../fortran/gfortran-mod-15/mpich/`, maybe this can be used instead, but how to tell the compiler?

**Edit1:**

```
$ LANG="C" caf caf01.f90 
f951: Warning: Nonexistent include directory '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/../../fortran/gfortran-mod-15/openmpi' [-Wmissing-include-dirs]
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmpi_usempif08: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmpi_usempi_ignore_tkr: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmpi_mpifh: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopen-rte: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopen-pal: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhwloc: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -levent_core: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -levent_pthreads: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Error: comand:
   `/usr/bin/mpif90.openmpi -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/fortran/ -fcoarray=lib caf01.f90 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/open-coarrays/openmpi/lib/libcaf_openmpi.a`
failed to compile.
```

The compile-command is `caf`: /usr/bin/caf -> /etc/alternatives/caf -> /usr/bin/caf.openmpi -> /etc/alternatives/caf-openmpi -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/open-coarrays/openmpi/bin/caf. In this last file there are the lines

```
# Always make extensions module available, user can choose whether to `use` it or not
caf_pre_flags=("${mod_dir_flag}/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/fortran/")
```

but no line including `gfortran-mod-15`.

**Edit2:**

I made a (symbolic) link

`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/../../fortran/gfortran-mod-15/openmpi/`

->

`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/../../fortran/gfortran-mod-15/mpich/`.

The warning about the nonexistent include directory is gone, but the other errors remain:

```
LANG="C" caf caf01.f90 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmpi_usempif08: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmpi_usempi_ignore_tkr: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmpi_mpifh: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopen-rte: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopen-pal: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhwloc: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -levent_core: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -levent_pthreads: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Error: comand:
   `/usr/bin/mpif90.openmpi -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/fortran/ -fcoarray=lib caf01.f90 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/open-coarrays/openmpi/lib/libcaf_openmpi.a`
failed to compile.
```

Comment: How do you tell compiler now? What exact command do you execute? Do you use a Makefile or anything similar?

Comment: If you put `LC_ALL="C"` (or `LANG="C"`) in front of your command, you will get the error messages in English https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87745/what-does-lc-all-c-do

Comment: Hi @SandwichX I note there is a proposed edit from an anonymous user to your question. If you are trying to edit your question, you need to sign in first.

Comment: @veryreverie Thanks! Yes, it was me, but meanwhile the edit became more or less obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

Summing up "Using **CoArrays** with **gfortran** at **Ubuntu 22.04**" worked for me like this:

Installing the packages:

```
sudo apt-get install gfortran libcoarrays-dev libcoarrays-openmpi-dev libcaf-openmpi-3
```

Compiling:

```
gfortran -fcoarray=lib coarray-fortran-program.f90 -lcaf_openmpi
```

Running:

```
cafrun -n 3 a.out
```

(-n 3 = Number of Images) or with option

```
cafrun -n 3 --oversubscribe a.out
```

(if there is an error without this option).
*cafrun* might be replaced with *mpirun* or *mpiexec*.

Comment: `mpirun --use-hwthread-cpus a.out` uses automatically all cpus including the hardwarethreads, which might otherwise not be recognized as available slots and therefore could evoke  the error "not enough slots" and the need of _--oversubscribe_; _mpiexec_ can also use this option, _cafrun_ not. (Cp. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48835603/unable-to-use-all-cores-with-mpirun)